# What is wrong with my code C++ Fibo series

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 1;
    int num_temp;
    int num_next = 1;
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cout << num_next << "  ";
        num_next = num1 + num2;
        num1 = num2;
        num_temp = num2;
        num2 = num_next - num1;
        num1 = num_temp;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

EXPECTED: For n=9

```
0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21
```

Actual:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

I have to output the first "n" Fibonacci numbers however I think there is some problem in logic.. I can't find out what am I doing wrong. The first 3 or 4 elements are correct but then a problem occurs...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: Why do in 5 statements what can be done in 3? `cout << num1 << "  "; int temp = num2; num2 += num1; num1 = temp;`?

Comment: Why not `num2 = num_next;` ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to think about what the Fibonacci sequence is.

f(0) == 0
f(1) == 1
f(n>1) = f(n-2) + f(n-1)

A lot of people write this recursively, but of course, that means you end up re-calculating a lot. So then you get into optimizing it. And yes, you can do it in a single loop.

I would keep:

```
int fibuMinus1 = 1;
int fibuMinus2 = 0;

cout << fibuMinus2 << " " << fibuMinus1;
for (int index = 2; index < n; ++index) {
   int thisFibu = fibuMinus1 + fibuMinus2;
   fibuMinus2 = fibuMinus1;
   fibuMinus1 = thisFibu;
   cout << " " << thisFibu;
}
```

Or something like that. It can definitely be simpler than you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

I will give an additional answer that may help other users.

The basic message is: Any calculation at runtime is not necessary! Everything can be done a compile time. And then, a simple lookup mechanism can be used. That will be the most efficient and fastest solution.

---

With Binet's formula, we can calculate that there are only **very few** Fibonacci numbers that will fit in a C++ `unsigned long long` data type, which has usually 64 bit now in 2021 and is the "biggest" available data type. Roundabout 93. That is nowadays a really low number.

With modern C++ 17 (and above) features, we can easily create a `std::array` of all Fibonacci numbers for a 64bit data type at **compile time**. Becuase there are, as mentioned above, only 93 numbers.

So, we will spend only 93*8= 744 **BYTE** of none-runtime memory for our lookup array. That is really negligible.

We can easily get the Fibonacci number n by writing `FIB[n]`.

And, if we want to know, if a number is Fibonacci, then we use `std::binary_search` for finding the value. So, the whole function will be:

```
bool isFib(const unsigned long long numberToBeChecked) {
    return std::binary_search(FIB.begin(), FIB.end(), numberToBeChecked);
}
```

FIB is a compile time, `constexpr std::array`. So, how to build that array?

We will first define the default approach for calculation a Fibonacci number as a `constexpr` function:

```
// Constexpr function to calculate the nth Fibonacci number
constexpr unsigned long long getFibonacciNumber(size_t index) noexcept {
    // Initialize first two even numbers 
    unsigned long long f1{ 0 }, f2{ 1 };

    // Calculating Fibonacci value 
    while (index--) {
        // get next value of Fibonacci sequence 
        unsigned long long f3 = f2 + f1;
        // Move to next number
        f1 = f2;
        f2 = f3;
    }
    return f2;
}
```

With that, Fibonacci numbers can easily be calculated at runtime. Then, we fill a `std::array` with all Fibonacci numbers. We use also a `constexpr` and make it a template with a variadic parameter pack.

We use `std::integer_sequence` to create a Fibonacci number for indices 0,1,2,3,4,5, ....

That is straigtforward and not complicated:

```
template <size_t... ManyIndices>
constexpr auto generateArrayHelper(std::integer_sequence<size_t, ManyIndices...>) noexcept {
    return std::array<unsigned long long, sizeof...(ManyIndices)>{ { getFibonacciNumber(ManyIndices)... } };
};
```

This function will be fed with an integer sequence 0,1,2,3,4,... and return a `std::array<unsigned long long, ...>` with the corresponding Fibonacci numbers.

We know that we can store maximum 93 values. And therefore we make a next function, that will call the above with the integer sequence 1,2,3,4,...,92,93, like so:

```
constexpr auto generateArray() noexcept {
    return generateArrayHelper(std::make_integer_sequence<size_t, MaxIndexFor64BitValue>());
}
```

And now, finally,

```
constexpr auto FIB = generateArray();
```

will give us a compile-time `std::array<unsigned long long, 93>` with the name FIB containing all Fibonacci numbers. And if we need the i'th Fibonacci number, then we can simply write `FIB[i]`. There will be no calculation at runtime.

---

The whole example program will look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// All the following will be done during compile time

// Constexpr function to calculate the nth Fibonacci number
constexpr unsigned long long getFibonacciNumber(size_t index) noexcept {
    // Initialize first two even numbers 
    unsigned long long f1{ 0 }, f2{ 1 };

    // calculating Fibonacci value 
    while (index--) {
        // get next value of Fibonacci sequence 
        unsigned long long f3 = f2 + f1;
        // Move to next number
        f1 = f2;
        f2 = f3;
    }
    return f2;
}
// We will automatically build an array of Fibonacci numbers at compile time
// Generate a std::array with n elements 
template <size_t... ManyIndices>
constexpr auto generateArrayHelper(std::integer_sequence<size_t, ManyIndices...>) noexcept {
    return std::array<unsigned long long, sizeof...(ManyIndices)>{ { getFibonacciNumber(ManyIndices)... } };
};

// Max index for Fibonaccis that for an 64bit unsigned value (Binet's formula)
constexpr size_t MaxIndexFor64BitValue = 93;

// Generate the required number of elements
constexpr auto generateArray()noexcept {
    return generateArrayHelper(std::make_integer_sequence<size_t, MaxIndexFor64BitValue>());
}

// This is an constexpr array of all Fibonacci numbers
constexpr auto FIB = generateArray();

// All the above was compile time
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------


// Check, if a number belongs to the Fibonacci series
bool isFib(const unsigned long long numberToBeChecked) {
    return std::binary_search(FIB.begin(), FIB.end(), numberToBeChecked);
}

// Test
int main() {

    const unsigned long long testValue{ 498454011879264ull };

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << "Does '" <<testValue << "' belong to Fibonacci series?  --> " << isFib(testValue) << "\n\n";

    for (size_t i{}; i < 10; ++i)
        std::cout << i << '\t' << FIB[i] << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

---

Developed and tested with Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019, Version 16.8.2

Additionally tested with gcc 10.2 and clang 11.0.1

Language: C++ 17